# Browse functionality Indexing strategy

Tags: dspace

In Version 1.8.x,  could someone explain what indexing framework/techniques is used for the Browse index. That is, what is used ? SOLR, the Database Directly ? A cache.

It seems that there is a difference when discovery is activated (As per the documentation). There, Solr is suppose to be used.

Hence my questions here are:

1. In the first scenario (without discovery) What does the Browse functionality use to index the metadata or whatever else it index ?
2. In the Second Scenario (with discovery) same question ?
3. Finally, if someone could point me to the configuration or the class file involved that would be great. Especially I'm curious to know how does Adding Discovery changes the indexing strategy of the Browse functionality and maybe the search itself as well. I can investigate things myself, but having a big picture and some indication as to where to look at would be such a boost.

Answer (score 1):

In DSpace 1.x and 3.x, the browse index was a Lucene index stored in [dspace-install]/search.  Metadata from the database and full text content from bitstreams are extracted into Lucene.

If the Discovery index is not enabled, then the search box will query Lucene.  If the Discovery index is enabled, the search box queries SOLR.

In DSpace, the Lucene index has several limitations compared to the Lucene index.  The SOLR index is aware of user authorizations and presents authorization-aware results.  The Lucene index may return items that a user cannot access.

The following link should point you to the configuration files: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC18/Discovery

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. Just for clarification, that Discovery is enabled or not, has no incident on the Browse index ? It only has an incidence on the Search Index ? Are they originally the same index ? Moreover, In term of config file, what is the name of the service used by the browse index. Shouldnt its consumer be connected to it somehow? The same goes for the Search which through the consumer should connect to the discovery service or the same service as the Index Browser.

Comment: I would simply like to connect the dot visually. I presume the consumer are the one dealing with data modification event and asking to index items and etc...

Comment: Just to be nitpicky, the non-Discovery scenario isn't 100% correct -- [dspace-install]/search does hold a lucene index, but it only powers the search. Non-discovery browse is powered by special database tables (bi_xyz). In Discovery, search and browse are both powered by the same thing (Solr).

Comment: In DSpace 5.2, you can see that the discovery event consumer is enabled here: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5.2/dspace/config/dspace.cfg#L749 -- like you said, that listens for item modifications and updates the discovery index accordingly. The class for that event consumer is set up a few lines further down. In 1.8, there were consumers for search/browse instead: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-1.8.3/dspace/config/dspace.cfg#L641